# Remove corners from rectangle shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I've been trying to create a rectangle where the corners have been removed in a "sharp" way, for lack of a better word.

We're already able to do something similar to what I want by using the "Radius" sliders, or simply creating a round rectangle.

[image]

The key difference here is that the corners are simply rounded off while I'm looking for a "hard cut" so to say.

Comment: Which one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEaB5.jpg

Comment: Didn't know it had a specific term attached to it! Bevel-style is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's easier to do this [automatically in Illustrator](https://imgur.com/a/blZJ7Je).  It's called a chamfer, and can be applied using Illustrator's Live Corner functionality.  Why are you using Photoshop for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super up to date with recent PS versions, but I'm pretty sure there still isn't an option to change the corner type of a shape.

You could do it manually with the [`Convert Point` tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html#convert_between_smooth_points_and_corner_points). Basically make a rectangle shape with rounded corners and then click every anchor point once.

[image]

---

You could also use this script [Corner Editor.jsx](https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/corner-editor-photoshop-script/).

> The script calls it a chamfer.

[image]

---

...and you could also add a stroke with the same color and select the chamfered corner and align the stroke outside.

> You can also find these options in the `Window > Properties` panel.

[image]